# How to process (dynamically added) items at a given time?

Tags: c#, timer, task, scheduler, priority-queue

I've got a [(concurrent) priority queue](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1696822056)  with a timestamp (in the future) as the key and a function that should be called (/ an item that should be processed) when the time is reached as the value. I don't want to attach a timer to each item, cause there a lots of it. I'd rather go with a scheduler thread/task.

**What would be a good strategy to do so?**

---

With a thread running a scheduler... (pseudo-code follows)

```
// scheduler
readonly object _threadLock = new object();
while (true)
{
    if(queue.Empty) 
    {
        Monitor.Wait(_threadLock);
    } 
    else 
    {
        var time = GetWaitingTimeForNextElement();

        if(time > 0)
          Monitor.Wait(_threadLock, time);
        else
          // dequeue and process element
    }  
}
```

...and pulsing when adding elements (to an empty queue or adding a *new first* element)?

```
// element enqueued 
Monitor.Pulse(_threadLock);
```

---

Or with somehow chained (`Task.ContinueWith(...)`) Tasks using `Task.Delay(int, CancellationToken )`? This would need some logic to abort the waiting if a *new first* element is enqueued or to create a new task if no one is running. It feels like there is a simpler solution I'm not getting right now. :)

---

Or using a timer (very-pseudo-code, just to get the idea)...

```
System.Timers.Timer x = new System.Timers.Timer().Start();

x.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
{
    // dequeue and process item(s)

    x.Interval = GetWaitingTimeForNextElement(); // does this reset the timer anyway?
}
```

...and updating the interval when adding elements (like above).

```
// element enqueued 
x.Interval = updatedTime;
```

---

I'm also concerned with the precision of the wait methods / timers: Milliseconds is quite rough (allthough it might work) Is there a better alternative?

### Ergo...

Thats again a bunch of questions/thoughts - sorry for that - but there are so many options and concerns that its hard to get an overview. So to summarize: **What is the best way to implement a (precise) time scheduling system for dynamically incoming items?**.

I appreciate all hints and answers! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at [Reactive Extensions](http://rx.codeplex.com)?

Comment: @DanAbramov I feel like I should have looked at it, but getting into Rx seems like another 'big thing' (?), so at the moment I'd rather find a solution without it. Or do you think, this is _the_ preferred solution to work with? (Ok, I'll definitely put it on my list.) Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It *is* a big thing, definitely. However, if you have asynchronous sequence processing more than in one place, you should seriously consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing it like this:

1. Create a class called `TimedItemsConcurrentPriorityQueue<TKey, TValue>` that inherits from [`ConcurrentPriorityQueue<TKey, TValue>`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1696822056).
2. Implement an event called ItemReady in your `TimedItemsConcurrentPriorityQueue<TKey, TValue>` class that gets fired whenever an item is ready (for being processed) according to the timestamp. You can use a single timer and update the timer as needed by shadowing the `Enqueue`, `Insert`, `Remove` and other methods as needed (Or by modifying the source of `ConcurrentPriorityQueue<TKey, TValue>` and make those methods virtual so you can override them).
3. Instantiate a single instance of `TimedItemsConcurrentPriorityQueue<TKey, TValue>`, let's call that variable itemsWaitingToBecomeReady.
4. Instantiate a single object of `BlockingCollection<T>`, let's call that variable itemsReady. Use the [constructor that takes an `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287133.aspx) and pass it a new instance of `ConcurrentPriorityQueue<TKey, TValue>` (it inherits `IProducerConsumerCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`)
5. Whenever the event ItemReady is fired in itemsWaitingToBecomeReady, you deque that item and enqueue it to itemsReady.
6. Process the items in itemsReady using the [`BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381957%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method using a new task like this:

.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  foreach (var item in itemsReady.GetConsumingEnumerable())
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. I like the 'endless-iterating' aspect of the blocking collection. What is the idea of using the ConcurrentPriorityQueue as data source (instead of the empty constructor)? Doing so `T` would actually be `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`, with all keys containing no information (0 or the current time, depending on implememntation).

Comment: (However, I agree to have it, when implementing a more general version of `ItemsReady`, that does not depend on the key.)

Comment: @mvondano: In the following scenario it is useful to use a ConcurrentPriorityQueue in the BlockingCollection: Assume you are processing an item that takes long time to process. During processing, you add an item to itemsWaitingToBecomeReady that also becomes ready and then moved to ItemsReady. After that you add another item to itemsWaitingToBecomeReady but it has an **earlier** timestamp than the previous item. This item is also moved to ItemsReady. When using a ConcurrentPriorityQueue in the BlockingCollection, the next item will be the correct item even in this case.